# Deleting rows in google sheets using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I encountered the weirdest error while trying to delete rows that match a specific value using Google Apps Script.

Here is my Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("file.csv");
  
  var values = sheet.getRange("N2:N").getValues();
  
  var row_del = new Array();
    
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++)
  {
    if(values[i] == 'del'){
      row_del.push(i+2); // This line was added for debugging purposes.
     // sheet.deleteRow(i+2) was the line that was in this condition
     // (i+2) is used because row 1 has headers and the range starts from 0.
    }
  }
  
//  Logger.log(row_del);
//  GmailApp.sendEmail("my_email_address", "subject", row_del)
 
  for (var i = 0; i < row_del.length; i++)
  {
    sheet.deleteRow(row_del[i]);
  }
  
}
```

The code that I have written picks up the row numbers that should be deleted but not all these rows are deleted in my first try. I should execute my script a number of times for these rows to be deleted.

If my code has an error, it should show up and if the logic is wrong, incorrect rows must be deleted. I encounter neither of these scenarios and I should just execute this function multiple times.

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: Try deleting from bottom up:   `for (var i = row_del.length - 1; i>=0; i--)
  {
    sheet.deleteRow(row_del[i]);
  }`

Comment: This worked.. Thanks a lot soup. Can you please tell me why my code was not working? Isn't your logic the same as mine?

Comment: you can use sheet.deleteRows(1, 2); as well, deleting all rows at once

Comment: your code is fine as is if you sort the array in reverse order first:  let row_del_desc = row_del.sort().reverse(); then use teh sorted array to delete.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When a row is deleted from a sheet, the rows below it get renumbered even as the script continues to run. If the script subsequently tries to also delete those rows, the result is unpredictable. For this reason, when deleting rows one should proceed from bottom to top. In your case, like so:

```
for (var i = row_del.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
  sheet.deleteRow(row_del[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Each iteration will cause an API call, which is slow. Better you perform a batch update here.

Answer (score 5):

refer to lock function suggested by google team:

```
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000); // lock 30 seconds
  //do whatever you want here
  lock.releaseLock();
```

That way, you got your deleting job work once at a time! The system thread won't go on to other jobs until 30 seconds is up or releasing the lock.

google dev-document: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock

Answer (score 3):

To delete blank rows from a single named sheet, assuming column 1 has data in valid rows.
Search and delete from highest row number to lowest row number.

```
// Deletes any row whose first column is blank
// WARNING: Assumes any valid row has data in column 1
function deleteBlankRows() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

  for (var i = lastRow; i > 0; i--) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(i,1); 
    var data = range.getValue();
    if (data == '') {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it matter that you're getting the active sheet by name and then using `getActiveSheet` to get the last row. Could this possibly refer to 2 different sheets? I think you should update it to `sheet.getLastRow()`.

Answer (score 1):

increment i only if you didn't delete a row

```
function del_F_rows(){
 var i=1;
 while(!sht_balanceHistory.getRange(i,1).isBlank()){
  if(sht_balanceHistory.getRange(i,3).getValue()=="F")
     sht_balanceHistory.deleteRow(i);
  else
     i=i+1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete the rows alter the last row using the `deleteRows` function like this:

```
var maxRows = newsheet.getMaxRows(); 
var lastRow = newsheet.getLastRow();
if (maxRows-lastRow != 0)
{
  newsheet.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful to provide some additional details, that explain what this code is doing, and how exactly this addresses the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2020

A faster and a more modern JavaScript approach would be to use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to iterate backwards.

It makes more sense to [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)ten the `values` array since it concerns data of a single column.

**Solution:**

```
function myFunction() {
  const doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = doc.getSheetByName("file.csv");
  const values = sheet.getRange("N2:N").getValues().flat();
  values.reverse().forEach((r,i)=>{
      if (r=='del'){
         sheet.deleteRow(values.length-i+1);
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to sort records and delete all at once.

My following code will sort the data with `N/A` value and will delete all rows at once.

```
function DeleteErrorLine2() {
      var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ORDER SHEET"); //Get Open Lines Sheet
      var lastRow = SS.getLastRow();
      var range = SS.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, 33); //get range
      range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false}) // filter data descending   

      var cell = SS.getRange('B1');   // values stored in cell B      
      var ct = 1;  // starting row        
      while(cell.offset(ct, 0).getValue() == "#N/A" ) {
          ct++;
      }       
      if(ct!=1){
          ct = ct - 1 // minus 1 to get the last row
          SS.deleteRows(2, ct)
      }
      range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true}) // filter data again ascending
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, is this what it should look like?

```html
function myFunction() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var values = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

  var row_del = new Array();

  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++)
  {
    if(values[i] == 'N'){
      row_del.push(i+2); // This line was added for debugging purposes.
     // sheet.deleteRow(i+2) was the line that was in this condition
     // (i+2) is used because row 1 has headers and the range starts from 0.
    }
  }

//  Logger.log(row_del);
//  GmailApp.sendEmail("my_email_address", "subject", row_del)

  for (var i = row_del.length - 1; i>=0; i--) { sheet.deleteRow(row_del[i]); }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy pasting from: https://gist.github.com/dDondero/285f8fd557c07e07af0e

Instead of looping through the rows twice, you can count how mwny rows have been deleted, to calculate the correct index for the row that you will delete next.

```
function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[0] == 'delete' || row[0] == '') { // This searches all cells in columns A (change to row[1] for columns B and so on) and deletes row if cell is empty or has value 'delete'.
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: From Review: please add a description explaining how the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script I used to delete everything but certain values, but can be easiliy modified to keep certain strings and runs a lot faster than looping through all the data filters out and deletes the values you want to remove and bulk deletes. my data had about 10000 rows so loop would have taken forever.

```
function DeleteCertainRows(){

  columnCopy("D","Z","YourSheetName");//Copy from your target column in this case D to another column in this case Z

  replaceInSheet("Z","YourSheetName","keep String 1","keep");//find and replace the value with what you want to keep
  replaceInSheet("Z","YourSheetName","keep String 2","keep");//Can repeat for additional values

  DeleteValueInColumn("Z","YourSheet","keep");//filters and deletes all other values Column is case sensitive and cant go past Z

};

function replaceInSheet(repColumn,sheetname, to_replace, replace_with) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);

  var values = sheet.getRange(repColumn+'1:'+repColumn+sheet.getMaxRows());

  var textFinder = values.createTextFinder(to_replace); 
  var replaceall = textFinder.replaceAllWith(replace_with);

};

function columnCopy(copyfrm,copyto,sheetname){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
    var copyrange = sheet.getRange(copyfrm+'1:'+copyfrm+sheet.getMaxRows());
    var pasterange = sheet.getRange(copyto+'1:'+copyto+sheet.getMaxRows());

  copyrange.copyTo(pasterange);

};

function DeleteValueInColumn(colStr, sheetname, deleteval){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var filterRange=sheet.getDataRange();
  var myFilter = filterRange.createFilter();
  var CriteriaBuild = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria();
  var Criteria = CriteriaBuild.whenTextDoesNotContain(deleteval);//change to whenTextContains to delete your string value instead of everything else
  var myCriteria = Criteria.build();

  var str = colStr;
  var myCol = parseInt(str.charCodeAt(0) - 64);
  Logger.log(myCol);

  myFilter.setColumnFilterCriteria(myCol, myCriteria);

  var deleterange=sheet.getRange('2:'+sheet.getLastRow());
  sheet.deleteRows(deleterange.getRow(), deleterange.getNumRows());

  myFilter.remove();


};
```