# Split a Google Sheet into multiple tabs based on column values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I used a previous answer [(thanks kessy!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60674902/i-need-to-split-a-google-sheet-into-multiple-tabs-sheets-based-on-column-value) to split 7000 or so rows into 40 or so different tabs based upon values in a column. I ran the same script on another nearly identical file and I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 5, file "Code")". I tried with a greatly simplified file and get the same error. Any help getting this to work is very much appreciated.

```
        function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // This var will contain all the values from column C -> Room
  var columnRoom = sheet.getRange("C:C").getValues();

  // This var will contain all the rows
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  //Set the first row as the header
  var header = rows[0];

  //Store the rooms already created
  var completedRooms = []

  //The last created room
  var last = columnRoom[1][0]


  for (var i = 1; i < columnRoom.length; i++) {    

    //Check if the room is already done, if not go in and create the sheet
    if(!completedRooms.includes(columnRoom[i][0])) {

      //Set the Sheet name = room (except if there is no name, then = No Room)
      if (columnRoom[i][0] === "") {
        var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet("No Room");
      } else {
        var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(columnRoom[i][0]);
      }


      //append the header
      currentSheet.appendRow(header);
      currentSheet.appendRow(rows[i]);
      completedRooms.push(columnRoom[i][0])
      last = columnRoom[i][0]
    } else if (last == columnRoom[i][0]) {

    // If the room's sheet is created append the row to the sheet


      var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      currentSheet.appendRow(rows[i]);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is exactly your goal, but based on the error message you are getting it seems that you are not getting the active sheet properly. Instead, I would suggest you to specify the sheet by its name. Let's assume the desired name of the sheet you want to get is **Sheet1**. Then, in the first line of your function you can **replace** this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

with this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
```

I also optimized your code a little by removing all the unnecessary `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` calls:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetId");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  // This var will contain all the values from column C -> Room
  var columnRoom = sheet.getRange("C:C"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // This var will contain all the rows
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Set the first row as the header
  var header = rows[0];

  //Store the rooms already created
  var completedRooms = []

  //The last created room
  var last = columnRoom[1][0]

  for (var i = 1; i < columnRoom.length; i++) {    

    //Check if the room is already done, if not go in and create the sheet
    if(!completedRooms.includes(columnRoom[i][0])) {

      //Set the Sheet name = room (except if there is no name, then = No Room)
      if (columnRoom[i][0] === "") {
        var currentSheet = ss.insertSheet("No Room");
      } else {
        var currentSheet = ss.insertSheet(columnRoom[i][0]);
      }

      //append the header
      currentSheet.appendRow(header);
      currentSheet.appendRow(rows[i]);
      completedRooms.push(columnRoom[i][0])
      last = columnRoom[i][0]
    } else if (last == columnRoom[i][0]) {

    // If the room's sheet is created append the row to the sheet
      sheet.appendRow(rows[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I previously tried using getSheetByName, but I get the same null error. It seems like I'm not getting SpreadsheetApp.getActive() to recognize the active spreadsheet. I ran

Comment: @Darren can you please try this instead: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("IDofthespreadsheetfile");`

Comment: Thank you @Marios. For whatever reason, I had to openById() instead of getActive() for all lines. Thank you for teaching me how to get spreadsheets by ID!

Answer (score 1):

You can also run a loop within the loop and keep things server side for a faster result (at least it worked for me, I was having trouble with long spreadsheets timing out).

You have to know how many columns you want to pass over, maybe there is a better way to push the values than I have done (I only dabble in script).

```
function splitSheets() {
var theWorkbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var theSheet = theWorkbook.getSheetByName("Master");

//Let's delete any sheets that were previously split, so we can rerun the script again and again
    var sheets = theWorkbook.getSheets();

  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
     switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
     case "Master":
          break;
     default:
        theWorkbook.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
     }
  } 

  // This var will contain all the values from column C -> Your splitting Key
  var key = theSheet.getRange("C:C").getValues();

    // This var will contain all the rows
  var rows = theSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Set the first row as the header, get the range so we can keep the formatting
  var headerFormat = theSheet.getRange("2:2");

  //Store the rooms already created
  var completedSheets = [];

//We start at i=2 because we're on row 3, row zero for the button, row one for the header
  for (var i = 2; i < key.length; i++) {
//We don't want to run the loop if we've already created the blank page and the row key is also blank.    
    if(completedSheets.includes('Blank') && key[i][0] === ""){
    //do nothing
    }else{
    //Check if the room is already done, if not go in and create the sheet
    if(!completedSheets.includes(key[i][0]) ) {
 
      //Set the Sheet name = unique key (except if there is no name, then = Blank)
      if (key[i][0] === "") {
        var currentSheet = theWorkbook.insertSheet("Blank");
      } else {
        var currentSheet = theWorkbook.insertSheet(key[i][0]);
      }

      //To avoid pasting formulas, we have to paste contents, copying allows us to keep formatting
      headerFormat.copyTo(currentSheet.getRange(1,1),{contentsOnly:true});
      headerFormat.copyTo(currentSheet.getRange(1,1),{formatOnly:true});
      
//Now here find all the rows containing the same key address and push them, this way doing it server side
      var theNewRows =[];
      var b=0;
      for(var j = 1; j < rows.length; j++) {
        if((rows[j][2] == key[i][0]) || (rows[j][2] === '' && currentSheet.getName() == "Blank")){
          theNewRows[b]=[];//Initial new array
          theNewRows[b].push(rows[j][0],rows[j][1],rows[j][2],rows[j][3],rows[j][4],rows[j][5],rows[j][6],rows[j][7],rows[j][8]);
          b++;
        }
      }
      var outrng = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,theNewRows.length,9);//Make the output range the same size as the output array
      outrng.setValues(theNewRows);
   
//The new sheet name gets added to the completed sheets list and the value of var last is updated in prep of next step
      if(currentSheet.getSheetName() == 'Blank') {
      completedSheets.push('Blank');
      last = "Blank";
      }else{
      completedSheets.push(key[i][0])
      last = key[i][0]
      }
     }
    }
  }
//And return to the Master
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(theWorkbook.getSheetByName('Master'));
}
```

Example here, just click the button on the page
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pfeU2CFDbZbA4O0b4z80l5MyCKDNQnUdkpKlzODbAiI/edit?usp=sharing

It's not perfect, but hope it helps.