# Delete row when cell has text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to delete the entire row if the cell in column A has any content.

I'm new to this, but I've tried a couple of scripts online.

Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19gJOSufJwAN_J4zc-uGBdASDUeCCZwkCQztjvcrt7P0/edit?usp=sharing) to my spreadsheet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting rows in google sheets using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924842/deleting-rows-in-google-sheets-using-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 2):

```
function delRowIfColA() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(4,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]) {
      sh.deleteRow(i+4-d++);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Got this error _TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 4, file "Code")_

Comment: Perhaps you need to change the sheet name